# slideToggle halve of a div?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, toggleclass

Is it possible to use slideToggle from halve of a div to full and then back?

I have one solution with this code:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#myDiv").toggleClass("reveal-closed").toggleClass("reveal-open");
});
```

See working example http://jsfiddle.net/NHRzH/1/

But I would like to use for more slide effects and a better solutions without class involved

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

This script need to be repeated with 20-30 div with buttons (read more function)
Here is an example with slideToggle that's not working with half div http://jsfiddle.net/Xvxs3/

Comment: So you want to start out with 50% height of paragraphs with different length?

Comment: use animation instead to halve the css height property

Comment: I want to use approximately 150px high, and onClick change the height depending on content. All div's has different total height.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
.reveal-open {
  max-height: 100px;
}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: max-height .5s linear;
  transition: max-height .5s linear;
}
```

and the jquery

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#myDiv").toggleClass("reveal-open");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/NHRzH/4/

Comment: This solution requires the browser to support CSS transitions.

Comment: Thanks, but that example doesn't give me dynamic content, or do I missing something?

Comment: Actually, the beauty of max-height means that it doesnt actually have to expand to that height. Lets say your content is 100px tall.  If you set max-height to 900px, the div will still only expand to 100px!

Comment: I like your solution, however, I can't seem to get it work if I change the css to #myDiv{...} instead of div{...}. Have you got a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/NHRzH/12/

**CSS:**

```
#myDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    toggleDiv($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});

function toggleDiv(selector) {
    var $this = $(selector);

    //Close div, if open.
    if($this.hasClass('open'))
    {
        var originalHeight = $this.data('height');
        $this.animate({
                height: originalHeight},
                200,
                function() { $(this).removeClass('open'); });
        return false;
    }

    //Open the div
    var currentHeight =  $this.height();
        autoHeight = $this.css('height', 'auto').height()
        $this.data('height', currentHeight)
             .height(currentHeight).animate({
                                        height: autoHeight},
                                        200,
                                        function() { $(this).addClass('open'); });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDiv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
<button href="#myDiv">Show more</button>

<hr />

<div id="myDiv2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
<button href="#myDiv2">Show more</button>
```

**How it works.**

We assign an `href` value to the buttons, which we pass along to a `toggleDiv` function (which handles the toggling of the div).

The `toggleDiv` function will handle the state of the `div`, and toggle it either open or close based on it's current state.  It will go from mid-height to full-height (auto).

The complete working example can be viewed here, with multiple divs: http://jsfiddle.net/NHRzH/12/